# Start Mongodb for evermore

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a desktop application that use from Mongodb!
For every time I Should run `hhhh@kkkk:~$ mongod`
then run my program.

But I want run mongod for evermore.Is it possible?

Comment: which OS are you running this on?

Comment: My app is crossplatform but most users running on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows you can install mongo as Windows service. There are options for another platforms as well

```
mongod --install
```

This line of code installs mongodb as Windows service. Don't forget about --dbpath and --logpath :)